# When removing a `<li>` from a list of lis, I got styles wrongly applied to the next `<li>`. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, debugging, vue.js

I am doing a todo list in Vuejs. I am almost done with the behavior. However, when I removed a `<li>` from the list, I got the class `.completed` into the next `<li>`. Why is this happening?

This is a sample JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mercenariomode/34q6gxt1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because your click event is propogating to parent element of span i.e li and hence active is toggled.So to prevent this you need to stop your event from propogating further by using stop. Read for [details](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

```
<span v-on:click.stop="deleteTodo(index)">{{ todo.delete }}</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/k3b0umL1/

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this which I think would look better i.e separate the span of both cross symbol and task text.

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="addNewTodo">
      <input id="input-value" type="text" v-model="task">
      <button type="submit">Add todo</button>
    </form>

    <ul>
      <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
      <span :class="{ completed: todo.isActive }" @click="$set(todo, 'isActive', !todo.isActive)">
      {{ todo.task }}</span> <span v-on:click="deleteTodo(index)">{{ todo.delete }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```